# Ip address checker doesn't output IP address

Tags: python, request, ip-address, urllib, python-3.8

Following the code from [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/check-your-external-ip-address/) I have got an IP address checker. However instead of outputting an IP address it outputs `[]`. Code:

```
import urllib.request
import re

print("we will try to open this url, in order to get IP Address")

url = "http://checkip.dyndns.org"

print(url)

request = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

theIP = re.findall(r"d{1,3}.d{1,3}.d{1,3}.d{1,3}", request.decode('utf-8'))


print("your IP Address is: ",  theIP)
```

Expected output:

```
we will try to open this url, in order to get IP Address
http://checkip.dyndns.org
your IP Address is: 40.74.89.185
```

**The IP address there is not mine and comes from [HERE](https://udger.com/resources/ip-list/fake_crawler)**.

Real output:

```
we will try to open this url, in order to get IP Address
http://checkip.dyndns.org
your IP Address is:  []
```

I have just copied from the website and then fixed the errors. What have I done wrong. Help please...

My python version is idle 3.8.

Comment: In regex "d" is just a literal "d" character. "\d" matches decimal digits.

Comment: I do not understand what that means @jordanm . I have just copied and pasted stuff...

Comment: Read up on how to use regex and test your regex using an online utility such as this one: https://regex101.com/. The problem is that your regex is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that your regex where wrong:
I've updated the code and using requests get:

`findall` will return a list of elements since you are get only one ip back just use [0]

```
from requests import get
import re
iphtml = get('http://checkip.dyndns.org').text
theIP = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', iphtml)
print(f"Your IP is: {theIP[0]}")
```

Your code updated:

```
import urllib.request
import re

print("we will try to open this url, in order to get IP Address")

url = "http://checkip.dyndns.org"

print(url)

request = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

theIP = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', request.decode('utf-8'))


print("your IP Address is: ",  theIP[0])
```